# Turn a files content into an UploadedFile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a file saved in my application whose content I would like to create a laravel UploadedFile with.

```
 $content = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/Imports/example.csv'));

 // returns Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
 $uploadedFile = $this->someMethodToMakeLaravelUploadedFile($content);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new Uploadedfile

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

return new UploadedFile($path, $name);
```

In your case

```
$uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(storage_path('app/Imports/example.csv')), 'example.csv')
```